# Why does this setter method not work?

Tags: java, android, getter-setter

I am trying to get a variable and then set another variable with a setter method.

Here is the code I am talking about:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX);
    mIsCheater = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_CHEAT);
    mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].setHasCheated(mIsCheater);
}
```

Here I am getting mIsCheater and using it to set another variable.

However, when I go to run my app, the getter method returns false and mIsCheater returns true.

Here is that code:

```
Log.i(TAG,"mIsCheater = " + mIsCheater);
Log.i(TAG,"hasCheated = "+ mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getHasCheated());

if(mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getHasCheated()) {
    messageResId = R.string.judgment_toast;
} else {
    if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }
}
```

Here is the logger info:

```
11088-11088/geoquiz.android.tubbs.com.geoquiz I/QuizActivity﹕ **mIsCheater = true**
11088-11088/geoquiz.android.tubbs.com.geoquiz I/QuizActivity﹕ **hasCheated = false**
```

I do not understand this because I clearly call the setter/getter methods correctly. They are also the same current index and such.
I had it working for a second but then I changed something and now it isn't working.

Here is additional code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState()");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX,mCurrentIndex);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(KEY_CHEAT,mIsCheater);
}
```

Comment: What does the code for your onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b) look like?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting/setting it correctly?

Comment: try printing the index at both inside the if condition and next to your log

Comment: I have added my code for onSaveInstance and I've tried running Logs on the index. They are exactly the same. I am almost certain I am setting/getting correctly.

Comment: are u sure you are reading the right array field??

Comment: Yes I am. As I said in my post, I tweaked a few things and it worked before, Now it doesnt. I believe it's something to do with the setter method not doing properly.

Comment: We really need to see the rest of the code.  Especially the class that mQuestionBank is an array of.

Comment: Why do you need two variables to indicate the same concept? if s/he isACheater then s/he hasCheated (that is: s/he isACheater because s/he hasCheated). What am I missing in this logic?

Comment: I appreciate all the help But I have solved it. I post an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question.

If you notice, I was doing my assignment for the mCurrentIndex in the onCreate method.

onCreate is only called once and therefore my setter method is never called because savedInstanceState IS null. That setter method would only be called once I rotate the device and thus recalling onCreate.
However, onResume is called when I navigate back from CheatActivity and I simply placed my setter method in it.

My updated code took out hasCheated variable and simply called the getter method in its place throughout the code.

Thanks for the help guys!